# Оптимально посчитать количество элементов в масиве

Tags: c#, массивы, оптимизация, code-hunt

Доброго времени суток!

В продолжение к [Code Hunt](https://www.codehunt.com), еще один непонятный случай. Необходимо сосчитать количество букв 'a' в пришедшей строке.

Решение в лоб через цикл и инкремент переменной выдал 1 звезду за прохождение уровня. 
Решение через Linq выдало 2 звезды.

Как получить 3, тоже ума не приложу. Как еще более красиво решить задачу?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(string s) {
    return s.Where(x=>x == 'a').Count();
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Попробуй return s.Count(x=>x == 'a');

Comment: @gost, нет, те же 2 звезды. Тут что-то в корне алгоритма менять нужно, но как еще решить проблему подсчета элементов в массиве не знаю.

Comment: return Regex.Matches(s, "(a)").Count; не знаю что им надо... :)

Comment: @gost, бинго :-) 3 звезды через регулярку :-) Оформи как ответ.

Comment: @pincher1519: Это что, конкурс на самое неэффективное как по расходу памяти, так и по скорости решение?

* Прямой подсчёт эффективнее всего, т. к. прямо отображается на нативный ассемблерный цикл. Проверка границ будет выкинута оптимизатором.
* LINQ несколько менее эффективно, т. к. на каждой итерации цикла происходит косвенный вызов лямбды. Хотя оптимизатор может и заинлайнить.
* Регулярка хуже всего, т. к. её нужно откомпилировать, проинтерпретировать, создать результирующую структуру (объекты, представляющие вхождения), и изх всего этого многообразия взять лишь количество этих объектов.

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю по какому принципу дают эти балы за решение. Просто стараюсь находить решение задачи и после этого подстраивать решение под "3 звезды", набрав максимальное количество баллов.

Там много неточностей, например, на некоторых задачках, по какой-то причине через linq не проходит решение из-за переполнения int, а в лоб решение с использованием того же int, проходит.
Меня больше интересует там угадывание алгоритма решения, а уж на втором плане решение его, и на третьем плане решение его с максимальным количеством баллов.

Comment: @VladD, Может там за самое короткое написание решения? :-)

Comment: Мозг дело темное...

Comment: Да, уж. Чем меньше кода, тем больше очков там. Ну вот, посудите:

`Use a while loop to count the number of digits in the number x`

Написал:
`
int c = 1;
while((x /= 10) != 0){
 c++;
}
return c;`

Получил одну звезду. Долго думал. Оказывается, три звезды за:

`return x.ToString().Length;`

Comment: @Veikedo: `.ToString` — это что-то из [этой](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B_.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B4.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0) области.

Правильным вариантом было бы, по идее, решение через логарифм, т. к. количество десятичных цифр есть целая часть десятичного логарифма. Но такое решение сопряжено с обычными для вычислений с плавающей запятой проблемами точности.

Comment: Там же ([на стартовой странице](https://www.codehunt.com/))

написано -- 
`Microsoft Research` -- так что вы еще хотите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return Regex.Matches(s, "(a)").Count;
```